# Mass storage for timing critical applications

Tags: stm32, embedded, sd, freertos, data-storage

I am working on a data logger that requires measurements to be taken during narrow time windows. I have been storing the measurement data on SD cards, however, the write times are very inconsistent, usually a few ms for 1kB but occasionally over 100ms which blocks the timing critical measurements.

I am using an STM32L4 microcontroller, FreeRTOS, and SDIO configured with DMA. I had hoped that this would allow long writes to yield to more timing critical tasks however STM32 SDIO implementation does not seem to like being interrupted.

What other mass storage options are viable that have consistent write times?

Comment: I would look into the buffering scheme first. You also do not say what capacity. MB? GB? How often is occasionally? Every few minutes? Or a couple of times per second?

Comment: Any reason you can't thread your IO so that you decouple the write time from everything else?

Comment: Most likely SD card wear leveling algorithm that causes this. Try different SD cards, maybe ones with rated for the use you need. Can you try USB storage?

Comment: @Justme that. Also, any SD cards timings will typically get worse over time.

Comment: @DKNguyen It would be required to store at least a few gigabytes, we are collecting about 100 MB a day. Also always writing 1024 bytes at a time, the large delays are quite infrequent. Over 20ms roughly once ever 2-3 minutes and over 100ms every 4 hours. It's not consistent enough to be predictable though that's just the average.

Comment: @user1850479 I have tried this but without much success, I'd love to see any working examples. I have SD storage running in it's own FreeRTOS task and the SDIO peripheral is running over DMA. However if I try and yield to another timing critical task during a write it appears to just hang and never recover resulting in my buffer overflowing.  I think I need to go deep into STMs SDIO drivers to fix things. Currently theres no feedback FATfs returns FS_OK everytime just sometimes takes up to 100x longer than usual.

Comment: I'm not familiar FreeRTOS, but storage is not a timing critical task, and IO operations are expected to have variable latency. It sounds like you need to resolve the underlying software problem that is keeping you from threading your IO and then implement some basic buffering.

Comment: If it really is unavoidable and unfixable in software, sounds like a job for a FIFO large enough to accommodate that until the probability is vanishingly small that the buffer is full when multiple 100ms (or longer) transfers occur.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very wide range of performance and quality of SD cards.

"a SanDisk microSD card engineer reportedly stated that as many as one-third of all SanDisk microSD cards were counterfeit. "

You have a choice to create a FIFO buffer and/or get a better SD card to meet expectations.

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-mistakes-avoid-buying-next-microsd-card/